# Multithreading randomly slowing program down

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to use sockets to communicate between networks. To do so, the server is using multithreading to hasten the process.

Some of the time, the server runs fine and all is well. However, other times, the server runs very poorly (this usually lasts just about 10ish seconds). During this time, the cpu usage goes up to 25%, which to my understanding means it is using an entire core. All I am doing is telling the thread to run a function, and eventually to call join(), so I can then run the same function again. It looks like this:

```
void Server::update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            m_clientThreads[i].join();
            m_clientThreads[i] = std::thread(&Server::foo, this);
        }
    }
```

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely comes from the thread creation. Indeed, creating a thread is *expensive* (it takes roughly 60 us on my machine). Joining it is a bit costly too, especially if the function is not completed at join time. Moreover, `Server::foo` is likely to share data with the one of your main thread. As a result, it might slow down your main thread because of a possible shared resource contention (atomics, mutexes, cache lines, even hardware resources like the RAM). Creating a lot of threads in a short period of time also often results in a more erratic OS scheduling. In modern C++, the standard way of doing this is to use `std::async`. A more efficient way is to **make a pool of threads ahead of time and then move tasks into the pool**.